# The identifier id is missing for a query of my Entity

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I am using **Api-Plateform** in **Creating Custom Operations and Controllers**

I would like to get all the resources, and I create a service for customize my data Providers [**here**](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers)

```js
// in Controller
public function getListClient(Client $data) 
{
  $obj = $this
  ->productCollectionDataProvider
  ->getCollection($data);
  
  return $obj;
}


//=================================
// My service
//=================================
public function getCollection( $resourceClass,
$operationName = null)
{
     if (Client::class !== $resourceClass){
             throw new                      ResourceClassNotSupportedException();
         }
  // Autowiring repository
  $data = $this->repository->findAll();

   return $data;
       
 }


//=================================
// here my Entity
//=================================
/**
 * @ApiResource(collectionOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "special"={"route_name"="get_list_client"}
 * }) 
 * 
 */
class Client
{
   //.....
}



//=================================
// My Route
//=================================
get_list_client:
    path: /client/special
    methods: ['GET']
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\ApiClient::getListClient
        _api_resource_class: App\Entity\Client
        _api_collection_operation_name: special
```

I don't understand why,there is an error **The identifier id is missing for a query**

If anyone can explain to me **collectionOperations in Custom Operations and Controllers**

Answer (score 1):

You must mark the property containing the identifier of your entity with the following annotation: `@ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty(identifier=true)`. It should fix the problem.